# Syncronizing SVN servers (online and local)

Tags: svn, version-control

Hey. is there a simple way to sync my local svn server with an online one?
this is what i'm trying to do:

i'm working on several projects through online svn repos. but sometimes i go off the grid, and want to still be able to access all my repo history. i have no prob registring an svn server on my system (or, to be more exact, it is something i can do with no problems i can't handle), and i want it to sync with the online one when updating. possible?

Comment: Any chance you could use an alternate version control system like Git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[git-svn](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) would probably fit your needs very nicely (it does for me in very similar circumstances).

If you would prefer something a little closer to what you're currently doing, you may want to look into [svk](http://svk.bestpractical.com/view/HomePage).

There are a number of [questions here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-svn) about `git-svn`, and in general it's fairly easy to find info on it.

Comment: +1 for svk.  I fair bit less brain bending then git for what you want.